# Invoking PHP from Java

Tags: java, php, sql, database

I am trying to invoke some PHP scripts from inside my Java program so I can query / modify my database. I am totally new to databases and don't have a clue whats going on.

I am trying to call the following script from within java.

**Script**

```
<?php
include('test.php');

define("HOST", "localhost");

define("USERNAME", "xxxx");

define("PASSWORD", "xxxx");

define("DATABASE", "project_database");

mysql_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

mysql_select_db(DATABASE);

?>
```

**Java code**

```
 public static String excutePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters)
    {
      URL url;
      HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
      try {
        //Create connection
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
             "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
                 Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

        connection.setUseCaches (false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                    connection.getOutputStream ());
        wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();

        //Get Response  
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          response.append(line);
          response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

      } finally {

        if(connection != null) {
          connection.disconnect(); 
        }
      }
    }
```

What should the target URL be??

Comment: I remind you that the "Ask" button is meant to ask questions. What would you like to know? Additionally, your [tag:php], [tag:sql] and [tag:database] tags as totally irrelevant unless you have unreal expectations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to invoke a new process, see [java.lang.Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

However Java is capable of talking to your database directly via [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) and that's the approach I would strongly recommend. You don't have to spawn a new process or implement your solution in more than one language, and you can make use of numerous JDBC-related frameworks to make your life re. database access considerably easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the link of your page, could be something like '/localhost/yourPageInPhp.php

I assume you need to execute the script and just display its output within Java